# Rounding down numbers to set points with PHP

Tags: php

I have a basic 5 star rating system based on user submissions. depending on the rating, a particular image is shown.

`$user_rating` contains the rating number to one decimal place.

There are 'star' images with

> 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0

in the file names.

I need whatever number is contained in $user_rating to be rounded down to the nearest value above and stored in a new variable `$star_rating`. The numbers can never be rounded up. Even if `$user_rating` is 4.9, `$star_rating` should be 4.5.

Can someone help me achieve this?
Thanks

EDIT - using this but just returns original value - in this case 3.8

```
$star_rating = $user_rating;


 function roundToHalf($star_rating) {
     $temp = $star_rating * 10;
     $remainder = $star_rating % 5;
     return ($temp - $remainder) / 10;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function roundDownToHalf($number) {
     $remainder = ($number * 10) % 10;
     $half = $remainder >= 5 ? 0.5 : 0;
     $value = floatval(intval($number) + $half);
     return number_format($value, 1, '.', '');
}

define("ENDL", "\n");

print roundDownToHalf(4.9) . ENDL;
print roundDownToHalf(4.5) . ENDL;
print roundDownToHalf(3.8) . ENDL;
print roundDownToHalf(2.3) . ENDL;
print roundDownToHalf(1.0) . ENDL;
print roundDownToHalf(0.6) . ENDL;
```

**Output**

```
4.5
4.5
3.5
2.0
1.0
0.5
```

All in one compact function:

```
function roundDownToHalf($n) {
  return number_format(floatval(intval($n)+((($n*10)%10)>=5?.5:0)),1,'.','');
}
```

Comment: @polywhirl this is looking good, only thing, how can I make the whole number keep a `.0` on the end?

Comment: @polywhirl your code and output look perfect but I can't get it to work `$number = 3.8;

function roundDownToHalf($number) {
     $remainder = ($number * 10) % 10;
     $half = $remainder >= 5 ? 0.5 : 0;
     $value = floatval(intval($number) + $half);
     return number_format($value, 1, '.', '');
}`

Comment: it echos back out as 3.8 again

Comment: Shouldn't. Paste the code here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and hit execute. It works in all versions of PHP4 and PHP5. What is your input?

Comment: @polywhirl It does it on that link too. I copied your code but put `$number = 3.8;` above it to test. On phpsandbox it echos out 3.8??

Comment: It does not for me... weird? Try: http://writecodeonline.com/php4/ I tested `3.8` and it always gives me `3.5`.

Comment: @polywhirl. It was me being an amateur. I was echoing out `$number` not `roundDownToHalf($number)`. oops. Its all working perfectly now. Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

function roundRating($rating, array $ratings)
{
  if (in_array($rating, $ratings))
  {
    return $rating;
  }

  foreach($ratings as $key => $value)
  {
    if ($value > $rating)
    {
      return $ratings[($key - 1)];
    }   
  }
  return FALSE;
}

$ratings = array(0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0);
$rating = 4.3;

if ($rate = roundRating($rating, $ratings))
  echo sprintf('%.01f', $rate);
```

**Demo: http://3v4l.org/BRBne**

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl It's a matter of replacing `[]` with `array()`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach:

```
function roundToHalf($star_rating) {
    return floor( $star_rating * 2 ) / 2;
}
```

This works because you're looking values evenly divisible by .5  . The result is a float.  I think you're better off getting back a numerical value, in case you want to use it for mathematical purposes.  Let your display code format it as needed.

Comment: Plus one. I was gonna suggest this.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by 10 to make it into an integer than use the modulus operator '%' to remove the remainder.  Then divide by 10 to make it back into a decimal.

```
 function roundToHalf($number) {
     $temp = intval($number * 10);
     $remainder = $temp % 5;
     return ($temp - $remainder) / 10;
 }
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, its just returning the original value. check the edit for my code. Thanks

Comment: Should be `$remainder = $temp %5;` also `$temp = intval($number*10);` would handle decimal values after the tenths.